# Show content of custom password field on mouseover

Tags: javascript

I need to hide a custom password field content and display it when a user needs to see and copy it. Using [Password Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_field) module is one way to go. But then Password Toggle module [doesn't seem to support](https://www.drupal.org/node/2345489) Password Field module yet. Using [QTips](https://www.drupal.org/project/qtip) module feels like overkill for just one small field on the whole website. So what are cheaper performance-wise alternatives?

Comment: Where is this password field? How are you adding it (with the form api)?

Comment: I've just created a node field using https://www.drupal.org/project/password_field through Drupal UI.